# purecss.io Grid Breaking in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, flexbox, yui-pure-css

I've noticed that in purecss.io Firefox grids don't work unless I set display=flex for each grid that I want to horizontally align and then stack in responsive. If I don't want them horizontal and to always stack (e.g. two pure-u-1 boxes on top of each other) then I can't use display=flex. However, using this breaks compatibility with IE8. Does anyone know how to fix it so purecss works for Firefox?

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer, it was not related to purecss.io but rather two the whitespace between divs. If there is a line break between neighboring divs then they stack, otherwise they work as expected. For an example see the following to jsfiddles:

```
Stacking: http://jsfiddle.net/XCDsu/982/
Horizontal: http://jsfiddle.net/XCDsu/3/
```